# Adding a linestring by st_read in Shiny/Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, line, shiny

I have a large shapefile. For a better perfomance I try to load data with `st_read()` from `sf package`. The official documentation states that it should be very easy to integrate the shapefile into Leaflet/Shiny. Nevertheless, it does not work.

```
Error message: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

It works with `rgdal`, but the performance is not that good. [Link](http://rhodyrstats.org/geospatial_with_sf/geospatial_with_sf.html)

I hope that someone can help me out.

small [TestData](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vqpw8g80g7bkkeg/AABNkXua74AQlsvgOZJnUCYCa?dl=0)

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

shapefile <- st_read("pathToshape")

shinyApp(
  ui <-fluidRow(
    column(8,leafletOutput("map", height="600px"))
  ),

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng=16.357795000076294, lat=48.194883921677935, zoom = 15) %>%
      addPolylines(data=shapefile, layerId = shapefile$id, group = shapefile$zeitver, color="red", weight=3,opacity=1)
  })
})
```

Comment: You haven't actually explained what your performance problem is. Does it take forever to start? Is the web browser slow and clunky? How "large" is your shapefile, and in what dimension - lots of features, lots of attributes, lots of detail? Maybe you can generalise your features?

Comment: The shapefile ist about 5mb. It takes about 8sec to read into a variable..that's too long. (I have simplified the shapefile as far as possible. For example: number of columns..simplify geometry is not an option yet) I have therefore read that one can read with `st_read ()` shapefiles twice as fast. But as you explained, you can't handle `sf` objects within `Leaflet()`. The perfomance in leaflet is actually quite good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your test data is a dead link now, but I had a similar issue trying to plot `sf` linestrings and polygons in `leaflet`. The full error was

```
Error in if (length(nms) != n || any(nms == "")) stop("'options' must be a fully named list, or have no names (NULL)") : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I was able to successfully plot my geometries by dropping the Z dimension from the line and polygon with `st_zm`. Here is an example:

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

# create sf linestring with XYZM dimensions 
badLine <- st_sfc(st_linestring(matrix(1:32, 8)), st_linestring(matrix(1:8, 2)))

# check metadata for badLine
> head(badLine)

Geometry set for 2 features 
    geometry type:  LINESTRING
    dimension:      XYZM
    bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 3 xmax: 8 ymax: 16
    epsg (SRID):    NA
    proj4string:    NA
    LINESTRING ZM (1 9 17 25, 2 10 18 26, 3 11 19 2...
    LINESTRING ZM (1 3 5 7, 2 4 6 8)

# attempt map; will fail
> leaflet() %>%
+   addTiles() %>%
+   addPolygons(data = badLine)

Error in if (length(nms) != n || any(nms == "")) stop("'options' must be a fully named list, or have no names (NULL)") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

# try again!

# drop Z and M dimensions from badLine
goodLine <- st_zm(badLine, drop = T, what = "ZM")

# map; will plot successfully!
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = goodLine)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loading the data with `st_read` creates `sf` objects, very different things from loading with `readOGR` or `shapefile` or `readShapePoly`, which produce `sp` objects. `addPolylines` currently only supports `sp` objects.

Even if it did support `sf` objects it probably wouldn't speed your application up much, since `leaflet` needs everything in `geoJSON` format. You may have hit a scaling limit of the shiny-leaflet system and need to rethink your application.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! And what about using `mapview()` inside `renderLeaflet()` for `sf` objects? It will probably have no influence on the speed..am I right?